# Integrating sonarqube with Ldap

Tags: ldap, continuous-integration, sonarqube, integration, devops

I google a lot but I couldn't find an answer for how to integrate LDAP with sonarqube. Most of the documents are showing that we need to modify in /sonarqube-6.2/conf/sonar.properties as below;

```
# LDAP configuration 
# General Configuration 
sonar.security.realm=LDAP 
ldap.url=ldap://myserver.mycompany.com 
ldap.bindDn=my_bind_dn 
ldap.bindPassword=my_bind_password 

# User Configuration 
ldap.user.baseDn=ou=Users,dc=mycompany,dc=com 
ldap.user.request=(&(objectClass=inetOrgPerson)(uid={login})‌​)
ldap.user.realNameAttribute=cn ldap.user.emailAttribute=mail 

# Group Configuration 
ldap.group.baseDn=ou=Groups,dc=sonarsource,dc=com 
ldap.group.request=(&(objectClass=posixGroup)(memberUid={uid‌​}))
```

but the thing is I could find any block with LDAP integration as above in sonar.properties. Do I need to add these lines manually or will it be there already? I also tried with plugin but I couldn't find the next steps using plugin after installation.

Comment: # LDAP configuration
# General Configuration
sonar.security.realm=LDAP
ldap.url=ldap://myserver.mycompany.com
ldap.bindDn=my_bind_dn
ldap.bindPassword=my_bind_password 
# User Configuration
ldap.user.baseDn=ou=Users,dc=mycompany,dc=com
ldap.user.request=(&(objectClass=inetOrgPerson)(uid={login}))
ldap.user.realNameAttribute=cn
ldap.user.emailAttribute=mail 
# Group Configuration
ldap.group.baseDn=ou=Groups,dc=sonarsource,dc=com
ldap.group.request=(&(objectClass=posixGroup)(memberUid={uid}))

Comment: those LDAP details should be in the question body not the comments! Please [edit](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/42776653/edit) your question and add it there, so the configuration is actually readable and with the rest of the configuration.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

LDAP-related properties are not in the SonarQube built-in *sonar.properties* configuration file because out-of-the box SonarQube does not have LDAP capability.

Keep in mind that SonarQube has a plugin-based architecture. LDAP functionality comes with the [LDAP Plugin](https://docs.sonarqube.org/display/PLUG/LDAP+Plugin) . That documentation page details the various configuration properties, together with some examples.

Comment: thank you for your response @Nicolas. But the thing is do I need to add this code by myself in sonar.properties? `sonar.security.realm=LDAP

ldap.url=ldap://myserver.mycompany.com

ldap.bindDn=my_bind_dn

ldap.bindPassword=my_bind_password

 

# User Configuration

ldap.user.baseDn=ou=Users,dc=mycompany,dc=com

ldap.user.request=(&(objectClass=inetOrgPerson)(uid={login}))

ldap.user.realNameAttribute=cn

ldap.user.emailAttribute=mail
# Group Configuration

ldap.group.baseDn=ou=Groups,dc=sonarsource,dc=com

ldap.group.request=(&(objectClass=posixGroup)(memberUid={uid}))`

Comment: Yes, LDAP Plugin configuration must be set in _sonar.properties_. Actual properties values depend on your LDAP deployment.

Comment: Thak you @Nicolas

Comment: Can you explain a bit more. Because I am a beginner. I need to paste the above LDAP configuration in sonar.properties right?. then what is the use of sonar LDAP plugin that I installed